# Yank to host clipboard when using nvim from Docker (WIndows)

Tags: neovim, os-clipboard, wsl, windows

- NVIM v0.9.1
- Windows10

I'm using neovim in Docker Desktop. Usually, when I use nvim in WSL2, I can yank / paste via "+y / "+p. But if neovim in Docker Desktop doesn't support the same feature.

I check https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#how-to-use-the-windows-clipboard-from-wsl but it seems there aren't any useful information .

Can someone kindly help me to achieve this?